# Cannot access Beautifulsoup second div

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a html code below, I want access "sisa 1" .. but always failed, anyone can help?

```
<dd>
<div class="product-list__stock--branch">
 <div data-id="2" data-stock="1" class="product-list__stock product- 
       list__stock--ready">
    <b>Online / COD</b>
    <span>Stok tersedia</span>
 </div>
 <div data-id="3" data-stock="1" class="product-list__stock product- 
     list__stock--ready">
    <b>Toko Semarang</b>
    <span>Stok tersedia</span>
    <span class="tag2 tag--warning" style="color:white;">Sisa 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list__stock--available-branch-trigger product- 
     list__stock--available-branch-trigger--sold-out">Tidak tersedia di 
     toko lain.
  </div>
</div>
</dd>
```

Comment: Div tags do not match up, are you sure the HTML is correct?

Comment: yes, I scrap it from an online webstore in Indonesia

Comment: `let x = document.querySelector("span.tag2.tag--warning").innerText;`

Comment: The result still None

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with BeautifulSoup:

```
div = soup.find("div", {"data-id": "3"})
```

This returns the div containing Sisa 1. To get the actual "Sisa 1" text:

```
text = div.contents[2].text
```

Comment: I tried this, the result is None Here my sript :  link = requests.get('https://www.jakartanotebook.com/apexel-lensa-kamera-smartphone-universal-clip-110-wide-angle-lens-apl-hd5w-black').text
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')

div = soup2.find("div", {"data-id": "3"})
try :
    text = div.contents[2].text
except Exception as e:
    text = None
    text="Not found"
print(text) ... I'm sorry i'don't know how to write in this comment box...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class to access the element like this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<dd>
<div class="product-list__stock--branch">
 <div data-id="2" data-stock="1" class="product-list__stock product- 
       list__stock--ready">
    <b>Online / COD</b>
    <span>Stok tersedia</span>
 </div>
 <div data-id="3" data-stock="1" class="product-list__stock product- 
     list__stock--ready">
    <b>Toko Semarang</b>
    <span>Stok tersedia</span>
    <span class="tag2 tag--warning" style="color:white;">Sisa 1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="product-list__stock--available-branch-trigger product- 
     list__stock--available-branch-trigger--sold-out">Tidak tersedia di 
     toko lain.
  </div>
</div>
</dd>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
all_rows = soup.find(class_="tag2")

print(all_rows.text)
```

Comment: @NugrohoMoristianto Did you copy the exact same code?

Comment: here my code :  link = requests.get('https://www.jakartanotebook.com/apexel-lensa-kamera-smartphone-universal-clip-110-wide-angle-lens-apl-hd5w-black').text
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(link,'lxml')

all_rows = soup2.find(class_="tag2")
try :
    text1 = all_rows.text
except Exception as e:
    text1 = None
    text1="Not found"
print(text1)

Comment: @NugrohoMoristianto Can you send a link to the code (can't copy it).

Comment: [link]https://www.jakartanotebook.com/apexel-lensa-kamera-smartphone-universal-clip-110-wide-angle-lens-apl-hd5w-black

Comment: @NugrohoMoristianto Each website has different tags

Comment: So, how to grab "sisa 1" in my case ?

Comment: You will have to check the website for which tag it has